# A* pathfinding causing lag Unity3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, path-finding

Recently, I tried creating an A* pathfinding program to move a character around to an end point. Running it, however, causes the unity editor to run at about one frame every two seconds. Any optimizing tips?

Here is the pathfinding algorithm

```
public class pathfinding : MonoBehaviour {
    List<pathnode> path;
    Heap<pathnode> open;
    Heap<pathnode> closed;
    List<pathnode> neighbors;
    pathnode current;
    grid g;

    private void Start() {
        g = GetComponent<grid>();
    }

    public int getDistance(pathnode a, pathnode b) {
        int x = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Abs(a.position.x - b.position.x));
        int y = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Abs(a.position.z - b.position.z));
        if (x > y) {
            return (14 * y) + (10 * (x - y));
        }
        else {
            return (14 * x) + (10 * (y - x));
        }
    }
    public void run(List<pathnode> path, pathnode start, pathnode end) {
        open = new Heap<pathnode>(g.width * g.height);
        closed = new Heap<pathnode>(g.width * g.height);
        open.Add(start);
        start.calc(0, 0);
        while (open.Count > 0) {
            current = open.RemoveFirst();
            closed.Add(current);
            if (current == end) {
                while (current != start) {
                    path.Add(current);
                    current = current.parent;
                }
                path.Reverse();
                return;
            }
            neighbors = new List<pathnode>();
            foreach (pathnode p in g.free) {
                if (Vector3.Distance(p.position, current.position) <= Mathf.Sqrt(2)) {
                    neighbors.Add(p);
                    p.calc(getDistance(p, start), getDistance(p, end));
                }
            }
            foreach (pathnode p in neighbors) {
                if (closed.Contains(p)) {
                    continue;
                }
                int newDist = current.g + getDistance(current, p);
                if (newDist < p.g || !open.Contains(p)) {
                    p.calc(newDist, getDistance(p, end));
                    p.setParent(current);
                    if (!open.Contains(p)) {
                        open.Add(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the grid of pathnodes

```
public class grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    LayerMask ignore;
    public List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<pathnode> nodes = new List<pathnode>();
    public List<pathnode> free = new List<pathnode>();
    public List<pathnode> blocked = new List<pathnode>();

    [SerializeField] public int width;
    [SerializeField] public int height;
    [SerializeField] int count;
    [SerializeField] private bool debug;
    private void Awake() {
        ignore = LayerMask.GetMask("ground");
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < height; k++) {
                Vector3 point = new Vector3(i, transform.position.y, k);
                points.Add(point);
                pathnode node = new pathnode(point);
                nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        count = free.Count;
        free.Clear();
        blocked.Clear();
        foreach(pathnode n in nodes) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
            if (Physics.Raycast(n.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit, maxDistance, ~ignore)) {
                blocked.Add(n);
            } else {
                free.Add(n);
            }
        }
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(transform.position.x - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - .5f),
                new Vector3(transform.position.x + width - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - .5f),
                Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(transform.position.x + width - .5f,  transform.position.y, transform.position.z - .5f),
                new Vector3(transform.position.x + width - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + height - .5f),
                Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(transform.position.x + width - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + height - .5f),
            new Vector3(transform.position.x - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + height - .5f),
            Color.green);
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(transform.position.x - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + height - .5f),
            new Vector3(transform.position.x - .5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - .5f),
            Color.green);
        if (debug) {
            foreach(pathnode p in free) {
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f), 
                    new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    Color.green);
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    Color.green);
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    Color.green);
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    Color.green);
            }
            foreach (pathnode p in blocked) {
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    Color.red);
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    Color.red);
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x + .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    Color.red);
                Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z + .4f),
                    new Vector3(p.position.x - .4f, p.position.y, p.position.z - .4f),
                    Color.red);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

here is the pathnode script itself

```
public class pathnode : IHeapItem<pathnode> {
    public Vector3 position;
    public pathnode parent;
    public int f;
    public int g = 0;
    public int h = 0;
    int heapIndex;

    public pathnode(Vector3 p) {
        position = p;
    }

    public void setParent(pathnode p) {
        parent = p;
    }

    public int calc(int i, int j) {
        g = i;
        h = j;
        f = g + h;
        return f;
    }
    public int HeapIndex {
        get {
            return heapIndex;
        }
        set {
            heapIndex = value;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(pathnode nodeToCompare) {
        int compare = f.CompareTo(nodeToCompare.f);
        if (compare == 0) {
            compare = h.CompareTo(nodeToCompare.h);
        }
        return -compare;
    }
}
```

and here is the heap i use to organize my nodes

```
public class Heap<T> where T : IHeapItem<T> {

    T[] items;
    int currentItemCount;

    public Heap(int maxHeapSize) {
        items = new T[maxHeapSize];
    }

    public void Add(T item) {
        item.HeapIndex = currentItemCount;
        items[currentItemCount] = item;
        SortUp(item);
        currentItemCount++;
    }

    public T RemoveFirst() {
        T firstItem = items[0];
        currentItemCount--;
        items[0] = items[currentItemCount];
        items[0].HeapIndex = 0;
        SortDown(items[0]);
        return firstItem;
    }

    public void UpdateItem(T item) {
        SortUp(item);
    }

    public int Count {
        get {
            return currentItemCount;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) {
        return Equals(items[item.HeapIndex], item);
    }

    void SortDown(T item) {
        while (true) {
            int childIndexLeft = item.HeapIndex * 2 + 1;
            int childIndexRight = item.HeapIndex * 2 + 2;
            int swapIndex = 0;

            if (childIndexLeft < currentItemCount) {
                swapIndex = childIndexLeft;

                if (childIndexRight < currentItemCount) {
                    if (items[childIndexLeft].CompareTo(items[childIndexRight]) < 0) {
                        swapIndex = childIndexRight;
                    }
                }

                if (item.CompareTo(items[swapIndex]) < 0) {
                    Swap(item, items[swapIndex]);
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }

            }
            else {
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    void SortUp(T item) {
        int parentIndex = (item.HeapIndex - 1) / 2;

        while (true) {
            T parentItem = items[parentIndex];
            if (item.CompareTo(parentItem) > 0) {
                Swap(item, parentItem);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

            parentIndex = (item.HeapIndex - 1) / 2;
        }
    }

    void Swap(T itemA, T itemB) {
        items[itemA.HeapIndex] = itemB;
        items[itemB.HeapIndex] = itemA;
        int itemAIndex = itemA.HeapIndex;
        itemA.HeapIndex = itemB.HeapIndex;
        itemB.HeapIndex = itemAIndex;
    }
}

public interface IHeapItem<T> : IComparable<T> {
    int HeapIndex {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where should I start?

Fixed Update should be used for physics only. It runs at an fixed interval, if the framerate is low, it runs more often in the next one to compensate that. [Fixed Update - Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html#UpdateOrder)

You do a raycast for every single node. If you have 1000 nodes, that's 1000 raycasts, per Agent, multiple times a frame.

Pathfinding isn't a continuous process, instead it is something you call once and then save the path to let your agent follow the path, it shouldn't be in any update call at all.

And on top of that you are drawing lines in the editor, every frame, for every node, multiple times a frame.

Optimisations:

- Don't run it in any update, run it "on demand" with a limit, like 1-2 path calculations per frame
- Don't raycast every frame, do it once or if you have to do it continously, only raycast on valid paths, paths currently used by agents. And not all at once, but a fixed number of tiles per frame instead
- you could use a shader for debug drawing, so you don't have to draw it every frame

Use the Profiler with DeepProfiling enabled to see precisely where performance problems occur.
[Unity Profiler - Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html)

I hope that was helpful.